I can't reset initialRoute screen in my root stack - React Native
I am using @react-navigation/native upgraded current version but i am trying to reset the index 0 using the CommonAction.reset() not working
scenerio: I am in the login page once i loggined the splash screen in my root stack initially showing 3 seconds delay then navigate tot eh dashboard my question is why the splash screen is showing initially i already tried lot of things to reset the initialScreen while login or logout not working
type SplashScreenProp = NativeStackNavigationProp<RootStackParamList, 'Splash'>;

const Splash = () => {
    const navigation = useNavigation<SplashScreenProp>();
    navigation.dispatch(
                    CommonActions.reset({
                        index: 0,
                        routes: [{ name: 'TabRoot' }],
                    })
                );

const RootNavigator = () => {
    return (
        <HeaderButtonsProvider stackType="native">
            <RootStack.Navigator
                screenOptions={{
                    headerBackTitleVisible: false,
                    headerTitleStyle: screenOptions,
                    headerTitleAlign: 'center',
                }}>
                <RootStack.Screen name="Splash" component={Splash} options={{ title: '', headerShown: false }} />
                <RootStack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} options={{ title: '', headerShown: false, animation: 'fade' }} />
                <RootStack.Screen name="TabRoot" component={TabNavis} options={{ title: '', headerShown: false }} />
                <RootStack.Screen
                    name="Settings"
                    component={Settings}
                    options={{
                        title: 'Settings',
                        headerTitleStyle: screenOptions,
                    }}
                />


Please provide MRE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

You can directly reset to particular screen by writing below code:
 navigation.reset({ routes: [{ name: 'Your Screen Name' }] })

Updated:
Also you can reset it by navigationContainer Refrenece:
export const navigationRef = React.createRef();


<NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>
    //Your screens
</NavigationContainer>


navigationRef.current &&
    navigationRef.current.dispatch(
      CommonActions.reset({
        index: 1,
        routes: [
          {
            name: Screen.DASHBOARD,
          },
        ],
      }),
    );


Thanks, buddy. I tried many solutions, like resetting the screen with code such as navigation.reset({ routes: [{ name: 'TabRoot' }] }), navigation.dispatch(StackActions.replace('TabRoot')), and navigation.dispatch(CommonActions.reset({ index: 0, key: null, routes: [{ name: 'TabRoot' }] })).
I also tried other approaches, like using the getState() method to get the current state, but none of these worked in my splash screen component.

You have to replace Splash screen with your login screen and After login it will render based on conditional state.

You can check my updated answer for the navigation container reference option to reset it

You can solve this issue using conditional rendering.
For example, like this:
<Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
  {appInitialized ? (
    <Stack.Screen name={STACKS.AuthStack} component={AuthStackNavigator} />
  ) : (
    <Stack.Screen name={STACKS.SplashScreen} component={SplashScreen} />
  )}
</Stack.Navigator>

Alternatively, you can display the splash screen in a modal to avoid using it in the navigation since it's only needed during the project initialization.

Hey buddy, thanks for your answer. Yes, I already tried using conditional rendering with boolean state maintenance in my app, but that's not a proper approach in the root stack file. My question is: why is the splash screen showing initially after I've logged in? The splash screen appears for about 2 seconds and then disappears. Why does this behavior occur in my app after I've implemented the reset logic in my splash screen? Technically, I have a solution, but it's not proper code. If possible, please provide me with a reset screen solution.

could u share Splash screen code component code?
I usually manage SplashScreen in Modal.
<>

<Screen .../>
</StackNavigator
</>

Hey buddy, you're a really active guy, but I can't share the entire code here because of Stack Overflow's character limit. Can you give me your dummy email, and I'll share my entire code, dude?
